# Averageif based on a word within a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use the `averageif` formula to find the average for a specific word contained in a cell under the `Tag column`.

Referring to the example I have shown attached, I want to find the average of totals for Canada/USA/Europe/America respectively.

The data set is much larger and will be changing but that's an example of what it might look like. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36YqZ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to the community! What is the question _more specifically_? What approaches have you tried, and why did they not work? Try to be as specific as you can, since it will help people to provide more higher-quality answers.

Comment: It would be best to provide a link to a test sheet, and also as per comment above, to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=averageif(C:C,"*Canada",B:B)
```

adjusting the country name to suit, or parameterising it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it and double checked it by filtering by region and choosing with cells to average. It came up with different answers.